# Outlook Interop Copy MailItem

Tags: com, interop, outlook, add-in

I know I've seen this question before but I can't seem to find it again.

I want to use Microsoft Interop to copy a mail message from the inbox to a differnt folder. I know that other objects like appointment, and folder both have a CopyTo() method, but it is missing for MailItem.  The way I do it now is call MailItem.Copy and then move the copy to another folder.  I don't like this because it causes some "flicker" on the screen in outlook where you can see the Inbox grow and shrink as the emails are copied then moved.

Is there another solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Sad but this is the only way...

Look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/3dd2bd06-5738-4fb2-b628-0d7ab2be8157/